# Selective mouseenter/mousedown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**If this is too much information for one question, I shall post it into two if need be.**

I'm working on a web based app to make pixel art, while teaching myself Javascript and jQuery at the same time. This [SITE](http://afrohorse.netau.net/pixel) shows what I have accomplished so far.

As of right now, I have two issues, and I'm not sure that they are big enough to ask as separate questions.

1. When you click, it colors the square, when you click and drag, it will color all squares EXCEPT the one you initially clicked on.
2. When you click on a square and drag, that will undo squares that have been colored as you move over them. I can't seem to figure out how to change this behavior.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y94K8/7/) of what I have currently.

**HTML:**

```
Row Count:
<input type="text" id="rowcount" />Column Count:
<input type="text" id="columncount" />
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" />
<div id="box" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;

}
    #box {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;

}
td {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}

    tr {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.active {
    background-color:#aaa;
}
::selection {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
::-moz-selection {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

**And the most important part, the JS/jQuery:**

```
function createTable() {

mytable = $('<table cellspacing=0></table>').attr({
    id: "pixelGrid"
});
var rows = new Number($("#rowcount").val());
var cols = new Number($("#columncount").val());
var tr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({
        class: ["pixelRow"].join(' ')
    }).appendTo(mytable);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        $('<td></td>').text("").appendTo(row);
    }

}
mytable.appendTo("#box");


}

$(function () {
$(document).on('click', 'td', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$(function () {

isMouseDown = false

$('body').mousedown(function () {
    isMouseDown = true;
})
    .mouseup(function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
    if (isMouseDown) $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

});
```

So, my question is, How can I have it so that when I click and drag, it will color the square that was initially clicked on and how can I stop it from 'uncoloring' them as it passes over them?

Comment: so you don't want to change the color of the clicked square?

Comment: @ArunPJohny When you click it and it colors it, that is fine. When you click the mouse, hold in the mouse button and drag, it doesn't color the square that you initially clicked. I want it to color that square. Also, I want it to stop "uncoloring" the squares after you drag over ones that have been colored.

Comment: `If this is too much information for one question, I shall post it into two if need be.` Please don't

Comment: @TheWobbuffet The only reason I had said that is I know some questions can be overwhelming, especially when asking multiple things. Mine were related, but I didn't want to break any unspoken rules so I left that option there.

Comment: So, once they are colored, they should remain colored?  If you click on them again, should they go back to normal?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3R3fQ/1/ ? for issue 1

Comment: can you explain issue 2

Comment: @ArunPJohny That is perfect and fixed issue 1. Issue number 2. If you drag over the squares that have already been colored, I want them to stay colored. As of right now, it it setting them back to white.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Yes, clicking to reset them is okay, I just want the "dragging" to not reset them if possible.

Comment: @ArunPJohny That is perfect! That solves both problems I have been having!

Comment: @ArunPJohny I know this wasn't part of the question, but I'm curious. Is it possible to make it so using the left mouse button would apply "color" and using the right mouse button would set it back to white, even when dragging?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3R3fQ/4/ - there was an issue with the previous implementation

Comment: @ArunPJohny I notice if I accidentally click and drag on a border it can cause some strange behavior similar to issue 2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48737/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mathew-maclean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {

    //use a closure variable instead of making it a global one
    var isMouseDown = false

    $('body').mousedown(function (e) {
        isMouseDown = true;

        $('#pixelGrid td').data('hovered', false);

        //the mouse enter will fire only when mouse moved in from outside, here we register a mousemove handle which will be fired only once
        $(e.target).closest('.pixelRow td').one('mousemove.pixelGrid', function () {
            if (isMouseDown) {
                $(this).toggleClass('active').data('hovered', true)
            }
        })
    }).mouseup(function (e) {
        isMouseDown = false;
        $(e.target).closest('.pixelRow td').off('mousemove.pixelGrid');
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
        if (isMouseDown && !$(this).data('hovered')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active').data('hovered', true)
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3R3fQ/)

Comment: This is perfect, but still has an issue when clicking then holding the mouse down for a bit and dragging, or clicking on a border then dragging.